# Criterion to neglect poles of higher order

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

If I am having a fifth order system,  it is said that the dominant two poles nearer to the jw axis  determine the nature of the output, is there any criterion to neglect the other three poles , should we neglect them even if they are just to the left of the dominant poles...

Answer (score 0):

The dominant pole approximation makes analysis much easier. Basically, you choose the poles closest to the j$\omega$ axis because they have small real parts, so they will be slower to decay and therefore dominate the response (Analogous to a rate limiting step in chemistry).

I don't know of any hard and fast rule for which poles to neglect, it depends on the application. If possible it's probably best to experiment numerically. If you're a student then in the case of a class-work, if you're dealing only with 2nd order systems then it makes sense to drop the other 3, even if they're not too far from the two dominant poles.

You can read more here:
https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/PZXferStepBode/DomPole.html##section8

Comment: Maybe small note that this can mainly be used for the openloop response, such as with an impulse or step response. But when applying a sinusoidal input or when considering the closedloop it might not hold.